# How to use requireJs with envjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, envjs

Can someone give me some hints about how to combine **[bumblebee](https://github.com/ryangreenhall/bumblebee)** with **requireJs**? BumbleBee combines Rhino, JSpec, [Envjs](http://www.envjs.com/doc/guides#running-rhino) and Ant to provide an "out of the box" JavaScript testing toolkit.
Its very usefull for us because it makes a simple stand-alone-running possible in terminal on ubuntu-boxes.

Our whole JS-code based on requireJs-Modules, and it seems, that required modules are not loaded if they wehre required out of spec-files from envjs/bumblebee/rhine *(what kind of stuff ever may be responsible for that),* may be due to the fact of asynchronousity in requireJs.

**What i've done:**

1. i set up a BumbleBee-Environment following instructions on the [github-site](https://github.com/ryangreenhall/bumblebee) mentioned above
2. The command "ant examples" works fine and both test cases are running successfully
3. i added require-jquery.js to the dependencies (replacing jquery.js which was initially setup) (this way follows the Tutorial ["How to use jQuery with requireJS"](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)  - which runs successfully along our whole web application (and works fine)
4. i wrote some requireJS-Modules, required them in spec-files, and detected very quickly that they will not be loaded (the spec-files will be loaded, and the require-method will be executed, but not ins content)
5. then i played around with these [setup-hints](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) for combining requireJS with Node (rhino is mentioned here also)

**These files could be interesting:**

lib/bumblebee.js (which i considered as the entrypoint of the whole test-suite):

```
load('dependencies/js/env.rhino.1.2.js');
window.location="examples/fixture/fixture.html";

load('dependencies/js/jspec/jspec.js');
load('dependencies/js/require-jquery.js');

var runSpec = function(spec) {
    JSpec.exec(spec);
};


define(function(require) {
    console.log("A1");
    var dep = require('dependency');

    //The value returned from the function is
    //used as the module export visible to Node.
    return function () {};
});

require(['dependency'], function(d){
    console.log("A2");
} );


console.log("A3");

var specs = arguments;


jQuery.each(specs, function(index, spec) {
    runSpec(spec);
});

JSpec
  .run({ reporter: JSpec.reporters.Terminal, fixturePath: 'spec/fixtures' })
  .report();
```

Only "A3" will be printed to console, require-based Code will never be executed here.

Tthen I put the define/require-parts into the spec-files from the example-files and detected also, that i cant use modules with require because that they will not loaded and are not pressent.

Considering the original spec-file from BambleBee-Examples:

```
describe('Greeter', function() {

    load('examples/src/greeter.js');

    it('greets people', function() {
      expect(example.greeter().greet()).to(eql, 'Hello!');
    });
});
```

When I now use requireJS-specific modules, they will also not be loaded:

```
describe('Greeter', function() {

    load('examples/src/greeter.js');

    require(['dependency'], function(d){
        // do something with D...
        console.log("This will **NEVER** be printed");
    } );

    console.log("This **WILL** be printed");
    it('greets people', function() {
      expect(example.greeter().greet()).to(eql, 'Hello!');
    });
});
```

**The Question**:

Is there a way to combine Envjs with requireJS or is EnvJS the wrong testing tool for us?
Thanks a lot for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can refer to https://github.com/envjs/env-js/issues/7 to get detailed discussion between envjs and requirejs.
My solution is to use Phantomjs to run jasmine specs with CI, and you can find the sample project at https://github.com/xiaocong/xiaocong.github.com/tree/master/examples/coffee-bbb-amd-backbone-rest-contacts